# How to place carousel and text side by side bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I want a carousel to occupy half the page and to be aligned to the right while the text should be aligned to the left of the box.
I am using bootstrap. Here is my html:

```css
.main{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    #events{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly ;
    }
    
    .card{
      border-radius: 5%;
    }
    
    #myNavbar{
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    
    
    .impact{
      margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
      <div class="impact">
        <span>
           IMPACTING THE BANGLADESHI COMMUNITY IN OMAN!
        </span>  
      </div>
  
      <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide impact" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner impact" style="height: 500px;">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="{% static 'social_club/web1.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100 h-100" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="{% static 'social_club/web2.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
```

Could someone please tell me how I can make this possible? I have searched quite a lot about making the carousel only occupy half the page, but without results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Bootstrap 4` or `Bootstrap 5`, you have no need to add custom `CSS`. You can achieve this by using **Bootstrap classes**. In the following code snippet, I am using `Bootstrap 5`.

Here is the complete implementation of your code. Please make sure to add **closing tags** correctly.

**Note:** Don't add static height to any element for an accurate vertically center alignment effect.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="impact w-50">
    <span>
       IMPACTING THE BANGLADESHI COMMUNITY IN OMAN!
    </span>  
  </div>

  <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide impact w-50" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner impact">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://blog.getbootstrap.com/assets/img/2020/06/v5-new-logo.png" class="d-block w-100 h-100" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.winklix.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/f1ce6a0af5cb.jpg.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://htmlburger.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/lets-talk-about-bootstrap.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```